# Game character UV map with Alpha Eyelashes

Tags: uv, transparency, hair

I am trying to add hair and eyelashes to my game character using transparency (Alphas).

I was able to add eyelashes to the planes but I don't know how to make it work so that the eyelashes (and later the hair as well ) are on the same UV map as the rest of the character. When I UV mapped the rest of the body and then scaled the planes for the lashes smaller it obviously didn't show up anymore.

Should the eyelash image be already scaled to the left bottom corner (is is possible to do it in Blender or should I do it in Photoshop)?
If I want to bake the textures can the Alpha even be on the same color map or should the hair and eyelashes be separate? Can I bake everything together?
[image: Nr 1 is when I added the image. No 2 is the UV map I want to use.]

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I guess I got it. Just have to make a new texture file and placing it where the eyelashes on the UV map are located.

I haven't baked it yet but I guess it will work.[image: uv map]